Remove the rounded corners of an inner frame in a tcolorbox
I have the following LaTeX code which creates a warning message box using tcolorbox and puts a warning icon (the triangle warning sign) on the west side of the outer frame but in my test case instead of that warning sign I have used example-image-a from mwe package so that you might be able to run easily the example without downloading any additional file
Here is the code:
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[default]{opensans}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage[listings,skins,most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\definecolor{WarningBoxBg}{HTML}{000000}
\newtcolorbox{WarningBox}[1][]{%
  enhanced,
  boxsep=8pt,
  colback=white,
  colframe=WarningBoxBg,
  boxrule=0.25pt,
  leftrule=35pt,
  overlay unbroken and first ={%
    \node[rotate=0,
          anchor=center,
          minimum width=1cm,
          font=\Large\sffamily\bfseries,
          xshift=17.5pt,
          white]
          at (frame.west) {%
            \includegraphics[width=11mm]{example-image-a}
    };
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{WarningBox}
  This is my warning message!
  \begin{itemize}
  \item line-01
  \item line-02
  \item line-03
  \item line-04
  \item line-05
  \end{itemize}
\end{WarningBox}
\end{document}

Is there any way to remove the rounded corner of only the inner frame (the one which includes items list) and doing so only on the west(left) side of it?
Thanks in advance.

Please only ask one question per post.

You could use something like example-image-a for your question so everybody with a complete latex installation will be able to run your code without having to download additional images.

What do you mean by example-image-a, is that a package?

It is an image which is part of the mwe package. You don't need to load the package, it is sufficient to just have this package installed to use the image. Replace "Warning.pdf" in your code with it.

Thanks for the information. I didn't know that we had this possibility in LaTeX. This is very useful and interesting. I just updated the code in my question accordingly.

you don't need to specify the file type. Just using example-image-a without .jpg is in fact better because then each engine can choose the format best suited for this engine.

(and if you want more fun, use example-image-duck which comes from the duckuments package)

Thank for the remark, I updated the code accordingly. Also, now there is only one question (instead of three) about this code in the post.

Try
sharp corners=west,

Actually I tried this but this removes the rounded corners on the west both for the outer and inner frames. As I said, I just want those sharp corners on the west just for the inner frame.

You can manually draw the interior to control which corners should be sharp and which rounded:
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[default]{opensans}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage[listings,skins,most]{tcolorbox}
 \tcbuselibrary{hooks}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\definecolor{WarningBoxBg}{HTML}{000000}
\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox{WarningBox}[1][]{%
  enhanced,
  boxsep=8pt,
  colback=white,
  colframe=WarningBoxBg,
  boxrule=0.25pt,
  leftrule=35pt,
  interior hidden,
  underlay={
    \fill[tcbcolback] (interior.south west) -- (interior.north west) [rounded corners=\kvtcb@arc] -- (interior.north east) -- (interior.south east) [sharp corners] -- cycle;
  },
  overlay unbroken and first ={%
    \node[rotate=0,
          anchor=center,
          minimum width=1cm,
          font=\Large\sffamily\bfseries,
          xshift=17.5pt,
          white]
          at (frame.west) {%
            \includegraphics[width=11mm]{example-image-a}
    };
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{WarningBox}
  This is my warning message!
  \begin{itemize}
  \item line-01
  \item line-02
  \item line-03
  \item line-04
  \item line-05
  \end{itemize}
\end{WarningBox}
\end{document}



This is perfect! This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much for your time and your help and thanks again for that package.

@user17911 You're welcome!
